# android application displays an error when i click login button and register button

Tags: android

I have an application I am building, it has registration and login side and in the main application it has two tables: one for the registration and login, and the other table for the data operations. The application crashes when I open the login and also crashes when I tap the signup button. Here is my code for The database class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Created by WANDIE on 7/28/2016.
 */

public class DbHelperOperations {
//this is the class for datbase connectivity
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_AGE = "persons_age";
    public static final String KEY_SEX = "persons_sex";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT = "persons_contact";
    public static final String KEY_CIVIL = "persons_civli_status";
    public static final String KEY_WORK = "persons_work";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "persons_address";

    //values of the registration login application

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "uname";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "pass";


    //set up database  credentials
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNot";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";

     DbHelper ourHelper;
    private Context ourContext;
     SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;







    public DbHelperOperations(Context ourContext) {
        this.ourContext = ourContext;

    }
    public DbHelperOperations open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {

        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public void createEntry(Patient patient){//method for createng entry in databse for name and hotness

//insert the content values to the datbase
        ContentValues cvs=new ContentValues();
        cvs.put(KEY_NAME,patient.getName());
        cvs.put(KEY_SEX,patient.getSex());
        cvs.put(KEY_AGE,patient.getAge());
        cvs.put(KEY_CONTACT,patient.getContact());
        cvs.put(KEY_CIVIL,patient.getCiviStatus());
        cvs.put(KEY_WORK,patient.getNatureOfWork());
        cvs.put(KEY_ADDRESS,patient.getAddress());

        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cvs);

    }
//retrieve from database
    public String getData() {
        String result="";

        String query="SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE;

        Cursor c=ourDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);


        while(c.moveToNext()){
            result+=c.getString(0)+" "+c.getString(1)+" "+c.getString(2)+" "+c.getString(3)+ ""+c.getString(4)+ "" + c.getString(5)+""+ c.getString(6)+""+c.getString(7)+  " \n";

        }
        if(result.equals("")){
            return "no data";
        }

        /*
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iname) + " " + c.getString(ihotness) + "\n";

        }
        */



        return result;

    }

    public String getName(long l) throws SQLException {

       // String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
        String str="SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE "+KEY_ROWID+"="+l;

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(str,null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {

            String name = c.getString(1);
            return name;
        }
        return "";

    }

    public String getHotness(long l)throws java.sql.SQLException {
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,null,null,null,null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {

            String hotness = c.getString(2);
            return hotness;
        }
        return "";

    }

    public void updateEntry(long lRow, String mName, String mHotness) throws java.sql.SQLException {
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME,mName);
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_AGE,mHotness);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE,cvUpdate,KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow,null);


    }

    public void deleteEntry(long lRow1)  throws java.sql.SQLException{
        String sql="DELETE FROM "+DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE "+KEY_ROWID+"="+lRow1;
      //  ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,KEY_ROWID + " =" + lRow1,null);
        ourDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         public DbHelper(Context context)
         {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //called when u create a database
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_AGE + " INTEGER , " + KEY_SEX + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CIVIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_WORK + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL ) ");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL ) ");



        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//METHOD IS USED WHEN THE DATBASE HAS already been created
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

            String query  = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;
            db.execSQL(query);
            this.onCreate(db) ;


        }
    }

    public void insertContact(Contact c) {
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
        Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        int count =  cursor.getCount();
        values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,c.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,c.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,c.getPass());

        //this statement bellow inserts the contact object into the datbase
        ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        ourDatabase.close();




    }

    //database helper method to search for the password
    public String searchPass(String uname) {

        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT uname,pass FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        String a,b;
        b = "Not found...";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                a = cursor.getString(0);
                if (a.equals(uname))
                {
                    b = cursor.getString(1);
                    break;
                }
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return b;
    }

}
```

This is the code for the login class

```
public class MainLoginReg extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    EditText editUsername,editPasslogin;
    Button btnLogin,btnSignup;
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login_reg);

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignup_login);
    editUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsername_login);
    editPasslogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword_logiin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    editPasslogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    editUsername.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {

        case R.id.btnLogin:
            //Toast.makeText(MainLoginReg.this,"correct credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String str = editUsername.getText().toString();
            String pass = editPasslogin.getText().toString();
            String password = helper.searchPass(str);
            if (pass.equals(password))
            {

                Intent openLogin = new Intent(MainLoginReg.this,Display.class);

                openLogin.putExtra("Username",str);
                startActivity(openLogin);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainLoginReg.this,"Username and passwords don't match ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }



            break;
        case R.id.btnSignup_login:
            Toast.makeText(MainLoginReg.this,"Please signup here",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(MainLoginReg.this,Signup.class);
                startActivity(i);
                    break;
    }

}
```

}

and registration  is here

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button signup;
    EditText editname,editemail,editusername,editpasswd,editConfirmpass;

    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);
        editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        editusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editpasswd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
        editConfirmpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editConfirmPass);




        signup.setOnClickListener(this);
        editname.setOnClickListener(this);
        editemail.setOnClickListener(this);
        editusername.setOnClickListener(this);
        editpasswd.setOnClickListener(this);
        editConfirmpass.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnSignup:
                String namestr = editname.getText().toString();
                String emailstr = editemail.getText().toString();
                String unamestr = editusername.getText().toString();
                String pass1str = editpasswd.getText().toString();
                String pass2str = editConfirmpass.getText().toString();
                if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Unsuccessful! Passwords dont match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //   pass.show();
                    /*Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Successful");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("You have created an account");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();*/
                }
                else
                {
                    //insert the information in the database
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this,"Signup Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this,)
                    //we use the object of contact class
                    Contact c = new Contact();
                    c.setName(namestr);
                    c.setEmail(emailstr);
                    c.setUname(unamestr);
                    c.setPass(pass1str);

                    //insert into values db
                    helper.insertContact(c);

                }


                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: please post logcat

Comment: method com.example.hacker.nofityme.Signup.access$super
08-11 16:57:55.557 19029-19029/com.example.hacker.nofityme W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 75: Landroid/app/Activity;.getMediaController ()Landroid/media/session/MediaController;
08-11 16:57:55.557 19029-19029/com.example.hacker.nofityme D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0d4c
08-11 16:57:55.557 19029-19029/com.example.hacker.nofityme I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Activity.getSearchEvent, referenced from method com.example.hacker.nofityme.Signup.access$super

Answer (score 0):

You already defined the _id has a primary key in the table contacts, you can use AUTOINCREMENT and avoid get the next id after insertContact.

1. In create table "contacts" use autoincrement in _id column

   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL ) ");
2. Don't select * from contacts to get the id.
3. Don't put the id before insert new row.

   public void insertContact(Contact c) {
       ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();

   ```
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(COLUMN_NAME,c.getName());
   values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());
   values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,c.getUname());
   values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,c.getPass());

   //this statement bellow inserts the contact object into the datbase
   ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
   ourDatabase.close();
   ```

   }

Comment: i have not gotten you well Andres

Comment: Ok...  you coud use:  db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL ) ");

Comment: values.put(COLUMN_NAME,c.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,c.getUname());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,c.getPass()); it has stil failed

Comment: up i have  ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

Comment: i have removed  // String query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
      // Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
      // int count =  cursor.getCount();
       // values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);